# Easiest way to export amplitude from FeynArts to FeynCalc

Tags: packages, physics, feyncalc

I am having trouble calculating some unpolarized squared amplitudes with FeynArts+FormCalc and want to use FeynCalc to manually handle the amplitudes calculated by FeynArts.

What is the easiest way to collect the amplitudes calculated by FeynArts and define them in a way FeynCalc will understand (that is, with its own functions and definitions)?

Comment: Ahem, did you look at any of the [examples](https://feyncalc.github.io/examples) that come with FeynCalc? Almost all of them employ FeynArts, so the question is not so clear to me...

Comment: @vsht Oh, sorry about that. I had in fact not looked at the example gallery. I was sure that mathing feynarts with feyncalc was not a smooth process, but what I had in mind was formcalc+feyncalc (which do similar things and obviously 'don't do well together'), so I got confused. Thank you very much! I'm not sure if I should delete the question.

Comment: I'm not a mod, so it's not up to me to decide. In general, there is a [dedicated forum](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/discussions) for FeynCalc-related questions which is probably a more appropriate place to ask different things regarding the usage of the package.